# How to change the height of several rows only?

Tags: tables, resize

I want to enlarge the height of the 3rd and 4th rows such that there is enough space for the caption "Adjustable size?" and it looks nice. My setting below is my attempt but it still looks ugly for the 1st and 2nd rows.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{longtable,array,multirow,graphicx}

\LTpre=0pt\relax% to remove excessive border at the top of longtable.

\let\mc=\multicolumn
\let\mr=\multirow
\let\cl=\cline
\renewcommand\arraystretch{5}

\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt\relax
\begin{longtable}{|*4{c|}}\cl{3-4}
\mc{2}{c|}{\mr{2}{*}{}}                                     & \mc{2}{c|}{A container?}\\\cl{3-4}
\mc{2}{c|}{}                                                            & No & Yes \\\hline
\mr{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Adjustable size?}}
                                                                                    & No    & \verb|\cnode| & \verb|\circlenode| \\\cl{2-4}
                                                                                    & Yes & \verb|\Cnode| & \verb|\Circlenode|\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question

How to enlarge the height of the 3rd and 4th rows only?

Comment: Kind of an ugly work-around, but couldn't you just pad the two rows with empty lines, like `& & & \\  ` before and after the actual content?

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker: Your comment has been converted to a real solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461075/how-to-change-the-height-of-several-rows-only?noredirect=1#comment1159599_461075) from [Inquisitive Lurker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/108704/inquisitive-lurker):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{longtable,array,multirow,graphicx}

\LTpre=0pt\relax% to remove excessive border at the top of longtable.

\let\mc=\multicolumn
\let\mr=\multirow
\let\cl=\cline
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt\relax
\begin{longtable}{|*4{c|}}\cl{3-4}
\mc{2}{c|}{\mr{2}{*}{}}                              & \mc{2}{c|}{A container?}\\\cl{3-4}
\mc{2}{c|}{}                                         & No & Yes \\\hline
\mr{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Adjustable size?}}
                                                     &&&\\
                                                     & No   & \verb|\cnode| & \verb|\circlenode| \\
                                                     &&&\\\cl{2-4}
                                                     &&&\\
                                                     & Yes &    \verb|\Cnode| & \verb|\Circlenode|\\
                                                     &&&\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be to add some vertical space to each of the lines of interest, which would allow for a finer tuning.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{longtable,array,multirow,graphicx}

\LTpre=0pt\relax% to remove excessive border at the top of longtable.

\let\mc=\multicolumn
\let\mr=\multirow
\let\cl=\cline
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
\topskip=0pt\relax
\begin{longtable}{|*4{c|}}\cl{3-4}
\mc{2}{c|}{\mr{2}{*}{}} & \mc{2}{c|}{A container?}                 \\\cl{3-4}
\mc{2}{c|}{}            & No  & Yes                                \\\hline
\mr{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Adjustable size?~}}
                        & No  & \verb|\cnode| & \verb|\circlenode| \\[2em]\cl{2-4}
                        & Yes & \verb|\Cnode| & \verb|\Circlenode| \\[2em]\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Vertically unbalanced. :-)

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity True, it sure could be refined. But the means to add vertical space to individual lines is therein.